# Code output is different than expected in palindrome function

Tags: python, python-3.x, palindrome

Why am I not getting the correct output?

This is my code:

```
def main():
    num = 111

    if (isPalindrome(num)):
        print ("Palindrome",num)
    else:
        print ("Not a palindrome", num)


def isPalindrome(num):
    temp = num
    revNum = 1

    while temp > 0:
        rightNum = temp%10
        revNum = revNum * 10 + rightNum
        temp = temp/10

    print (revNum)
    if revNum == num:
        return True
    else:
        return False

main()
```

Output:

```
inf
Not a palindrome 111
```

It should return true and print Palindrome. I'm not understanding why am I not getting the output.

Comment: Start `revNum` at zero.

Comment: I did that too. It is not working.

Comment: btw thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Init
    revNum = 0
```

& use Floor division (//), normal division always results float

```
temp = temp//10
```

refer: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/operators

Try to debug with print statements for troubleshooting.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, floor division helped me!